# Format data in excel spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

[EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux9b2.png)
I am given a spreadsheet with data that needs to be formatted into a table. However, the data that is sent over cannot directly be converted into a table because of how it is formatted. In the example image, I need to combine Data B1 and Data B1and so on as well as Data D1 and Data D1 and so on into the same cell in the same row. How would I combine all the cells that span over 2 rows into the same cell and row. I need to automate this process using python.

I have to group them together so that i can convert the data to a table. If i were to convert the data to a table as it is, it would create 2 rows:

```
1:[Data A1, Data B1, Data C1, Data D1, Data E1], 
2:[' ', Data B1, ' ', Data D1, ' ']
```

but i want the data to look like this:

```
1:[Data A1, [Data B1, Data B1], Data C1, [Data D1, Data D1],DataE1]
```

I am trying to use python pandas but have not been able to achieve the correct results

```
import pandas as pd

# Excel file named 'data.xlsx' with a sheet named 'Sheet1'
excel_file = 'data.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

# Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Combine two cells in two rows into an array of values
df['Combined'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['Column2'], row['Column2']], axis=1)

# Save the modified DataFrame back to Excel
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: What does combine Data B1 and Date B1 mean? Join two strings together or what?

Comment: @user19077881 I have to group them together so that i can convert the data to a table. If i were to convert the data to a table as it is, it would create 2 rows:  {1:[Data A1, Data B1, Data C1, Data D1, Data E1],                                                   
  2: [' ', Data B1, ' ', Data D1, ' ']}                                                                            
  but i want the data to look like this:                                                                      
 {1:[Data A1, [Data B1, Data B1], Data C1, [Data D1, Data D1], Data E1]}

Comment: You could read the data into Pandas DF and then use Pandas to combine each pair of related rows to join the data values in a List.

Comment: share youre code to check problem

Comment: @komeilmajidi posted it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to combine the contents of 'Data B1' and 'Data D1' from two consecutive rows. You can adjust the columns as needed for your specific use case. Also, it handles the case where there is an odd number of rows in the original DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'data.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)

formatted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
    row1 = df.iloc[i]
    row2 = df.iloc[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(df) else None

    combined_row = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in ['Data B1', 'Data D1']:  # Specify the columns to be combined
            combined_row[col] = [row1[col], row2[col] if row2 is not None else None]
        else:
            combined_row[col] = row1[col]

    formatted_df = formatted_df.append(combined_row, ignore_index=True)

formatted_df.to_excel('formatted_output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: This worked for me. What if one of the columns could have a variable number of data points that needed to be combined instead of just assuming it is always 2?

Comment: When working with a column containing a varying amount of data points that require merging, you must be adaptable in your strategy. Instead of assuming a consistent pairing of rows, it is necessary to have a method in place to determine the appropriate number of rows to combine at each stage. This can be influenced by a particular condition or pattern within the data itself
and if the answer was useful for you, please accept it and upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Excel data is as shown and that the first column can be used as unique row labels then you could temporarily extend the first col values, use this for grouping, then remove List format if only one element and finally reset the index. The code below will handle a variable number of data points to be combined. It assumes there are no column names from a header row, but could simply be changed to use this. To see how this works you could print intermediary stages. Note that `if x[1] != x[1]` is just an easy way to check for NaN values (ie empty Excel cells).

```
import pandas as pd

#load excel file assuming no column headers
df = pd.read_excel("my_data.xlsx", header = None)

#extend values in column 0
df[0] = df[0].ffill()

#group, adjust format and reset_index
df = (df.groupby(0).agg(list)
      .map(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] != x[1] else x)
      .reset_index()
      )

print(df)
```

gives

```
         0                   1        2                   3        4
0  Data A1  [Data B1, Data B1]  Data C1  [Data D1, Data D1]  Data E1
1  Data A2  [Data B2, Data B2]  Data C2  [Data D2, Data D2]  Data E2
2  Data A3  [Data B3, Data B3]  Data C3  [Data D3, Data D3]  Data E3
```